# Comparison operators used for Boolean values

Tags: python, comparison-operators

How do comparison operators work? I thought they could be used only to compare numeric values, 5 <= 8, etc. But in this code *sets* are compared:

```
str = 'The quick Brow Fox'
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
alphaset = set(alphabet)

b = alphaset <= set(str.lower()) # Does it automatically extract length of objects?

print(len(alphaset))  # 26
print(len(set(str.lower())))  # 19
print(b)

26
15
False
```

I thought that it is impossible to do. `alphaset <= set(str.lower())`, you know literally is, e. g. `set() <= set()`. Does an operator implicitly call `len()` on such objects to find some numeric values to compare?

How does it know that one sequence is bigger, less or equal etc. to another?

Comment: I've found a better duplicate. Maybe not optimal. it's about `frozenset`. very similar to `set`

Comment: I suspect you actually wanted `alphaset >= set(str.lower())` there. FWIW, `alphaset.issubset(s.lower())` is a little more efficient than `alphaset <= set(s.lower())` since the former doesn't need to convert its arg to a set. (BTW, please don't use `str` as a variable name. That shadows the built-in `str` type, which can lead to confusing error messages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), which means that any class can implement methods that provide access to the standard operators.

For full documentation of what you can do in Python, including which methods a class can implement to support different operators, check out the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

For a description of how a built-in type like `set` implements its operators, see that type's documentation. For example, [documentation for the set type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> `issubset(other)`
>   `set <= other`
>
> Test whether every element in the set is in *other*.

There are a variety of [magic methods you can implement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) if you want to overload operators for your own classes. When you call `a < b` Python defers to [`a.__le__(b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__) if such a method exists.